# Object in tableViewCell are shown only when cell selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have custom **UITableViewCell**, which has **button** and **progress view**. It has **5 progress view** objects.

In `viewController.swift` I have a **struct** where **6 variables** (one of type button and five of type progress view) are.

When I'm clicking this button, I'm setting **struct variables** to **these five progress** view objects. Also `NSUrlSession` function starts which downloading file. Downloading progress must be shown in these progress views. And it working properly except moment that to see these **progress view** I must focus, **select** this cell. How can I fix it so by clicking this button all progress view will be shown in cell **without** its selecting?

Some code:

```
struct vis {
        static var b: UIButton!
        static var p1: UIProgressView!
        static var p2: UIProgressView!
        static var p3: UIProgressView!
        static var p4: UIProgressView!
        static var p5: UIProgressView!
}

vis.b = (sender as? UIButton)!
vis.p1 = (cell?.viewWithTag(5) as? UIProgressView)!
vis.p2 = (cell?.viewWithTag(6) as? UIProgressView)!
vis.p3 = (cell?.viewWithTag(7) as? UIProgressView)!
vis.p4 = (cell?.viewWithTag(8) as? UIProgressView)!
vis.p5 = (cell?.viewWithTag(9) as? UIProgressView)!
```

Comment: What do you mean by selecting the cell? You can scroll to a row if that's what you need to do by `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I mean when you tap the cell its background becomes grayed in color. So only in that case I can see all progress view and their value changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable cell selection by `tableView.allowsSelection = NO;` and then you can use `progressTintColor` and `trackTintColor` or `progressImage` and `trackImage` to manage the colors for your progress controls.